# TDS error: Sitecore web URL is not correct

Tags: tds

When I am trying to test TDS connection with Sitecore, it is failing at the very first step i.e. "Ensure Sitecore web URL is correct". However, URL is correct and I am able to browse the website with the same URL.

Answer (score 1):

Quick pointers to check:

1. Are you able to login to your Sitecore site? Try connecting while you are logged in to Sitecore in the Browser. I had faced this issue at times when I am not logged in to Sitecore, the connectivity fails.
2. See if you have the VS open as an administrator.
3. Check if the webroot has all the required access permissions.
4. Check the Sitecore deploy path is set correctly as per the site URL.
5. If you still face the issue, you should be able to see more info about the issue in the "Output" window if you switch to "Team Development for Sitecore" from the "Show Output From" dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to browse the site, i would suggest following

1. Copy the URL from a browser
2. Exit the VS studio and open it again in ADMIN mode
3. This time paste the URL in the field "Sitecore Web Url" and try again
4. If it does not work please paste the error you are seeing in "Team Development for Sitecore" option from the output window

Thanks and do let me know

Answer (score 1):

There are references to the project path and project url from each TDS csproj files,
ex : *C:\rootToYourProject\src\Feature\AFeature\TDS.YourProject.Feature.AFeature\TDS.YourProject.Feature.AFeature.scproj*

Take a look at these nodes and make sure it is well configured:

1. `<SitecoreWebUrl>Project Url</SitecoreWebUrl>`
2. `<SitecoreDeployFolder>yourDeployFolderPath (most likely in wwroot)</SitecoreDeployFolder>`

Make sure these paths corresponds to your actual setup.

If its misconfigured and you used the SIA, I would consider using SIF to install your project, when using the SIA you might face some limitations regarding the naming of your solution.