# TDS Connection Test Error - Check Sitecore Web url is correct

Tags: tds

When I am trying to test TDS connection with Sitecore, it is failing at the very first step i.e. "Check Sitecore web URL is correct". However, URL is correct and I am able to browse the website with the same URL. I am working with Sitecore containers. I took a look several pages like [TDS error: Sitecore web URL is not correct](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27134/tds-error-sitecore-web-url-is-not-correct) . But, unfortunately it didn't help me. Could you please suggest me any another ways of solution? And I need to add error output [image]

Comment: Is your certificate for xm1.cm.localhost valid and added to trusted certificates?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have added screenshots below.

Answer (score 1):

There can be lots of scenarios to test this issue. But I think first you need to check this.

1. Go to your `TDS` project and go to `properties`.
2. Now under the Build tab, you need to verify the `Sitecore Web URL` and `Sitecore Deploy Folder`.

Make sure these paths are correct.

Also, make sure to do the following practice.

1. Copy the URL from a browser.
2. Exit the `VS studio` and open it again in `ADMIN` mode.
3. Check if the webroot has all the required access permissions.

You can also check the below link for `Sitecore TDS Classic Deployment over HTTPS`

https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2017/08/31/sitecore-tds-classic-deployment-over-https/

Thanks

Comment: Could you pls check my answer that is shown above? Thank you!

Comment: @Anathema I've updated my answer. Please check this.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can use `HTTP://` instead of `HTTPS://` for your local `Sitecore` instances, but make sure that your site supports `HTTP` binding.
In IIS you can check bindings in this way:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, except for point 3, I am pretty sure for the others. I am using `docker container` for Sitecore, I guess webroot permissions are ok. But in any case, I have added those two lines into `docker` file

```
USER admin

RUN chmod 777 \inetpub\
```

So in that case, what would you recommend me to check? I have added certificates under trusted root certificates authorities for the local computer and current user. Even though they look like trusted on certificates, chrome screams that it is not. That might be the issue for `TDS` to connect.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: That should be an edit oy your question, not an answer. And if chrome says that your certificate is not trusted, TDS won't trust it neither. Are you sure it's in trusted store of your local machine (not user)? Are there maybe multiple certificates for the same domain?